# what is a word for sacrificing or giving up something as an act of remorse?

Tags: word-choice

I am seeking potential options for words that can be used to sacrifices that we make as an act of remorse.

For e.g :

i. Giving up game night/TV on account of securing less marks in the last exams

ii. Sacrificing your favorite toy because you hurt your friend

Comment: "fewer" marks — "less" for uncountables, e.g. less sugar, fewer lumps.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like *penance*.

> **penance** *noun*
>   Punishment inflicted on oneself as an outward expression of repentance for wrongdoing.
>   ‘he had done public penance for those hasty words’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/penance)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a harsher word, with different implications than what is being sought, but *punishment* seems to fit, by definition.

**[Punishment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/punishment):**

> the infliction or imposition of a penalty as retribution for an offense.

*Oxford Dictionary*

*'Sacrificing or giving something'* in this case is the self imposition of a penalty and the offenses would be what the remorse stems from.

In the examples outlined one has punished theirselves by giving up game night and sacrificing the favourite toy, the offenses can be considered as the lesser exam marks and hurting the friend.

Comment: looks like you got a downvote for offering too obvious an answer :)